# How to use generic function in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, precision

I have written this code in which if I uncomment the 2nd last line I get error - "template argument deduction/substitution failed: ". Is it because of some limit to generic functions in C++? Also my program doesn't print floating answer for the array `b`. Is there anything I can do for that? (sorry for asking 2 questions in single post.)

P.S: I have just started learning C++.

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 template <class T>
 T sumArray(  T arr[], int size, T s =0)
 {
     int i;
     for(i=0;i<size;i++)
     {  s += arr[i];
     }
     return s;
 }

 int main()
 {
     int a[] = {1,2,3};
     double b[] = {1.0,2.0,3.0};
     cout << sumArray(a,3) << endl;
     cout << sumArray(b,3) << endl;
     cout << sumArray(a,3,10) << endl;
     //cout << sumArray(b,3,40) << endl; //uncommenting this line gives error

     return 0;
 }
```

EDIT 1: After changing 40 to 40.0, the code works. Here is the output I get:

6

6

16

46


 I still don't get the floating answer in 2nd case. Any suggestion ?

Comment: The compiler already says this, but it deduces `double` from `b` and `int` from `40`. It doesn't go out of its way to guess through conversions and possibly compile a mistake. It's perfectly possible to make it ignore parameters when deducing types.

Comment: I've noticed your edit, but I strongly suggest you not to add new questions to the question body once you have already received an answer (or actually a lot of answers), because this will draw the answers somewhat unrelevant. You might want to ask a new question, but for this case, why do you think that the answer is not floating point? The answer is _exactly_ 46, be it integer or floating point. Try to put some non-integer numbers to `b` and check again.

Comment: @Petr Thanks.. I will take care not to ask 2 questions in a single post.

Comment: Just to avoid misunderstanding, asking two (related, of course) questions is ok as long as they are here from the beginning.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reason is that compiler can not deduce the type for `T`.

How it should understand what `T` is for your last example? The type of the first argument (`b`) is `double[]`, while it is `T[]` in the function definition. Therefore it looks like that `T` should be `double`. However, the type of the third argument (`40`) is `int`, so it looks like `T` should be `int`. Hence the error.

Changing `40` to `40.0` makes it work. Another approach is to use *two different* types in template declaration:

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 template <class T, class S = T>
 T sumArray(  T arr[], int size, S s =0)
 {
     int i;
     T res = s;
     for(i=0;i<size;i++)
     {  res += arr[i];
     }
     return res;
 }

 int main()
 {
     int a[] = {1,2,3};
     double b[] = {1.0,2.0,3.1};
     cout << sumArray(a,3) << endl;
     cout << sumArray(b,3) << endl;
     cout << sumArray(a,3,10) << endl;
     cout << sumArray(b,3,40) << endl; //uncommenting this line gives error

     return 0;
 }
```

Note that I had to cast `s` to `T` explicitly, otherwise the last example will lose fractional part.

However, this solution will still not work for `sumArray(a,3,10.1)` because it will cast `10.1` to `int`, so if this is also a possible use case, a more accurate treatment is required. A fully working example using c++11 features might be like

```
 template <class T, class S = T>
 auto sumArray(T arr[], int size, S s=0) -> decltype(s+arr[0])
 {
    int i;
    decltype(s+arr[0]) res = s;
    ...
```

Another possible improvement for this template function is auto-deduction of array size, see TartanLlama's answer.

Comment: In the code snippet " class S = T> " and  "T res = s ", do we need static_cast ? Is explicit typecasting safe?

Comment: @shane, for `class S=T` there is no cast, this is just a default template parameter. For `T res = s`, I can't find good references for this, but in general I think that implicit typecasting will be safer than explicit `static_cast`. The latter makes compiler think you know what you are doing, while the former will issue compile error or warning if this is something suspicious. However, you might want to ask a separate question on this.

Answer (score 4):

```
sumArray(b,3,40)
```

The type of `40` is `int`, but the type of `b` is `double[3]`. When you pass these in as arguments, the compiler gets conflicting types for `T`.

A simple way to fix this is to just pass in a `double`:

```
sumArray(b,3,40.0)
```

However, you would probably be better off allowing conversions at the call site by adding another template parameter. You can also add one to deduce the size of the array for you so that you don't need to pass it explicitly:

```
template <class T, class U=T, std::size_t size>
U sumArray(T (&arr) [size], U s = 0)
```

The `U` parameter is defaulted to `T` to support the default value for `s`. Note that to deduce the size of the array, we need to pass a reference to it rather than passing by value, which would result in it decaying to a pointer.

Calling now looks like this:

```
sumArray(b,40)
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40c26e055e3f020a)

Comment: Note that simply introducing `U` might not be enough, because it will suffer from float-to-int conversion problems if, for example, `U` is float, but `T` is int.

Comment: @Petr You're right, your solution is better. I'll leave this answer up for the auto array size deduction unless you wanted to put that in your answer.

Comment: You can go even further with `template <class C, class T = std::decay_t<decltype(*std::begin(std::declval<const C&>()))>> T sumArray(const C&, T = T{})`.

Answer (score 3):

In

```
template <class T>
T sumArray(  T arr[], int size, T s =0)
             ^                  ^
```

Both (deducible) `T` should match.

In `sumArray(b, 3, 40)`, it is `double` for the first one, and `int` for the second one.

There is several possibilities to fix problem

- at the call site, call `sumArray(b, 3, 40.0)` or `sumArray<double>(b, 3, 40);`
- Use extra parameter:

  ```
  template <typename T, typename S>
  auto sumArray(T arr[], int size, S s = 0)
  ```

  Return type may be `T`, `S`, or `decltype(arr[0] + s)` depending of your needs.
- make a parameter non deducible:

  ```
  template <typename T> struct identity { using type = T;};
  // or template<typename T> using identity = std::enable_if<true, T>;

  template <typename T>
  T sumArray(T arr[], int size, typename identity<T>::type s = 0)
  ```

Comment: I was searching for an answer mentioning non-deduced parameters. You got it :)

Comment: @Deduplicator: I find the name `std::enable_if` misleading for this case. But   `template<typename T> using identity_t = std::enable_if_t<true, T>;` seems a good compromise.

Answer (score 2):

Should be

```
sumArray(b,3,40.0)
```

so, `T` will be deduced to `double`. In your code it's `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option when deduction fails is to explicitly tell the compiler what you mean:

```
cout << sumArray<double>(b,3,40) << endl;
```

Comment: Do note that STL advocates [not doing this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKtHxKJRwp4) when possible.

Comment: @chris Occasionally it can be clearer this way, but yes, I would normally use one of the other options.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does not know whether `T` should be `int` or `double`.

You might want to do the following, in order to preserve the highest precision of the types passed:

```
template <class T, class S>
std::common_type_t <T, S> sumArray (T arr [], std::size_t size, S s = 0)
{
   std::common_type_t <T, S> sum = s;
   for (std::size_t i = 0; i != size; ++i)
   {
      sum += arr[i];
   }
   return sum;
}
```

The function you are writing, however, already exists. It's `std::accumulate`:

```
std::cout << std::accumulate (std::begin (b), std::end (b), 0.0) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Note that `accumulate` may be misused if initial value is not the 'correct' type (using `0` instead of `0.0` yields to `int` return type and not `double`).

Answer (score -1):

Templates only accept one type of data, for example if you send an array of double, then the runtime will deduce :

Template = double[]

so every time he will see it he will expect an array of doubles.

`sumArray(b,3,40)` passes "b" (which is an array of doubles) but then you pass "40" which the runtime cannot implicitly convert to double.

So the code

```
sumArray(b,3,40.0)
```

will work